# Integrating state space equations using Runge-Kutta 4?

Tags: integration, runge-kutta-methods

I have a state-vector which is of size 12x1, an input-vector $u$ which is of size 4x1, and A and B matrices which are of sizes 12x12 and 12x4 respectively, such that $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$. Using an initial state, my code uses forward Euler integration to integrate $\dot{x}$ over intervals of $dt$ and add it to the previous state to get the next state.

Now I'd like to make this more accurate using Runge-Kutta 4 integration. I watched some videos about RK4 for this task, so my knowledge about it might be a bit incorrect, but my understanding is that you find the step that you will add to the previous state by doing
$$
\frac{k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4}{6}
$$

How do I find the various $k$ coefficients? I found some pointers online but none of them work for a case like mine. All of the cases I've found use time as an input, but I don't think I can do that here. As I said, I'm pretty new to RK4 integration, so any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#The_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_method the wikipedia page gives a good explanation.

Comment: Maybe my anwer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645649/cannot-get-rk4-to-solve-for-position-of-orbiting-body-in-python) can give enough inspiration. If your Euler code works correctly, then the change to RK4 should not be too difficult. But that may depend on the organization or distribution of the state data, a flat vector is simplest for a straight-forward interface between model and integrator.

Answer (score 1):

If your equation is time-independent, simply omit time from the method.

From definition: $k_1 = f(x_k, t_k) = f(x_k, u_k) = A x_k + B u(t_k)$.

$$ k_i := f\Bigr( x_k + \Delta t \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_{i,j} k_j , u(t_k + c_i \cdot \Delta t)\Bigl)$$

There are many RK methods with 4 stages, but I am guessing you are using the "main one" (explicit one). The sum of $k$'s you have there is already multiplied with the $b$ coefficients. The coefficients for $a$ and $c$ are already inserted below.

Then
$$k_2 = A(x_k + \Delta t \frac{1}{2} k_1 ) +  B\cdot u(t_k + \frac{1}{2}\Delta t)$$
$$k_3 = A(x_k + \Delta t \frac{1}{2} k_2 ) +  B\cdot u(t_k + \frac{1}{2}\Delta t)$$
$$k_4 = A(x_k + \Delta t  k_3 ) +  B\cdot u(t_k + \Delta t)$$

The $u$ is just part of your function, I assume that this is a specified input.

To be completely clear:

$$
x_{k+1} = x_k + \Delta t \frac{k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4}{6} 
$$